# Difference between View and Subview - Android

Tags: android, view, android-view

What is the difference between a view and a subview in Android?

Comment: What do you mean by sub-view?

Answer (score 2):

there is no such thing called a 'subview', its just used to refer to a view inside another view.

Answer (score 2):

View is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components    (buttons, text fields, etc.).  and if we insert a view inside the another the its become Subview like  a linear Layout containing  a button view, here button is a subview

Answer (score 2):

Like Vinay said, there is no such a thing. But you have ViewGroup that contains other Views. For example, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc are derived from that class.
If you wish, you can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html